# How to use ndb in App Engine to query all entities of a kind with a certain value in the key pairs?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

If you have a bunch of `Spam` entities in the datastore, each with a key made from two pairs...

```
ndb.Key(AClass, a_string, BClass, b_string)
```

...how do you query for all `Spam` entities that have a given value for `a_string` in their key?

I'm trying to avoid doing...

```
hits = [ spam for spam in Spam.query() if spam.key.pairs()[0][1] == a_string ]
```

...and avoid adding a new property to store `a_string` in the entity, when it's already part of the key.

What's the best way to get a list of all `Spam` entities that had `'foo'` as the value of the second of four args in their `Key` constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement "how do you query for all Spam entities that have a given value for a_string in their key?" is an ancestor query - 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor

In your case you would do the following

```
result = AClass.query(ancestor=ndb.Key(AClass,a_string))
```